# Block access to a website with HTTPS?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, certificate

I hope my question is rightly placed within stackoverflow. If not, please excuse and point me into the right direction.

Is it possible to block access to a site with HTTPS?

I have a website that I would like to make accessible only to myself. Of course I could solve this programatically within the system, but I was asking myself whether it was possible to force HTTPS on port 443 for asking for a certain certificate and if not provided, then return some kind of 404 error or similar. So in other words I need to have the appropriate certificate on my client system in order to be able to access the site.

Is that generally possible? If yes, could someone point me to a documentation on that? Maybe for Apache if existent?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. And please don't cross-post.

Comment: From Apache's docs: [How can I require HTTPS with strong ciphers, and either basic authentication or client certificates, for access to part of the Intranet website, for clients coming from the Internet?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#intranet)